# List based printing python removing the last comma

Tags: python

I have a list of elements : answer = [1,4,2,4]
I need to output the list elements two at a time with spaces separated by a comma:
**EXPECTED OUTPUT : 1 4,2 4**

CODE:

```
for i in range(0,len(ans),2):
    print(ans[i],ans[i+1],end=",")
```

Output: **1 4,2 4,**
I cannot remove that last frigging comma.

Comment: The output should be in the same line as two space-separated integers. No string manipulation is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:
The list is even.

Logic: Just detect the last iteration of the code and don't print comma there.

```
ans = [1,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range(0,len(ans),2):

  last_iteration = len(ans)-(2) # Here 2(is same as the step size used in the loop)

  if i==last_iteration:  
    print(ans[i],ans[i+1])

  else: 
    print(ans[i],ans[i+1],end=",")
```

Output:

```
1 5,6 7,8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```py
ans = [1,4,2,4]
print(",".join([str(ans[i])+ " " + str(ans[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(ans),2)]))
>>> 1 4,2 4
```